# How to create more than one connection via Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Question is how can I create few connections, at least two connections for testing online changes at page ? It's only online chat.

At this time I have only

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before do
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Name",    with: user.name
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
end
```

But I'm looking for something like this:

```
let(:first_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:second_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

at connection: :first_connection do 
    before do
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Name",    with: first_user.name
        fill_in "Password", with: first_user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
    end
end

at connection: :second_connection do
    before do
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Name",    with: second_user.name
        fill_in "Password", with: second_user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
    end
end

# manipulate with connections
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, I think you have to create sessions manually. [From the doc](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara):

```
# For ultimate control, you can instantiate and use a Session manually.

require 'capybara'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit, my_rack_app)
session.within("//form[@id='session']") do
  session.fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@example.com'
  session.fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
end
session.click_button 'Sign in'
```

There are some other interesting things like using multiple windows. You can find them all in the docs. Also, since you said it is a live chat, take extra care because not all drivers support JavaScript and Ajax. You will probably need additional setup code.

Comment: i'm not well know capybara yet, but it's a right thing that i can create two sessions such as session_1 and session_2, and further use them like this: session_1.visit some_path and apply another rspec syntax with session name ? it looks right. I'm going to study capybara.

Comment: Yes, you probably can create two sessions, as the doc says. Also, if that answered your question, then close the question.